# TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'n_values' in python code

Tags: python-2.7

I am getting TypeError: **init**() got an unexpected keyword argument 'n_values' in python code
I am trying to run the code but always it is showing error.Please suggest a solution to solve this error

```
sample_files = ['10009_Pop_music.jpg', 
                 '10003_Rhythm_blues.jpg',
                 '10004_Reggae.jpg',
                 '10006_Rock_music.jpg',
                 '10005_Techno.jpg']

label_dict = {'Pop':1,
              'Rhythm':3,
              'Reggae':4,
              'Rock':5,
              'Techno':6,
             }
NUM_CLASSES = 7
one_hot = OneHotEncoder(n_values=NUM_CLASSES)

all_files = os.listdir(IMG_DIR)

# Get class weights
label_array = []
for file_ in all_files:
    vals = file_[:-4].split('_')
    label_array.append(label_dict[vals[1]])
    
cl_weight = compute_class_weight(class_weight = 'balanced', 
                                 classes = np.unique(label_array), 
                                 y = label_array)
train_files, test_files, train_labels, test_labels = train_test_split(all_files, 
                                                                      label_array,
                                                                      random_state = 10, test_size = 0.1
                                                                     )

val_files, test_files, val_labels, test_labels = train_test_split(test_files, test_labels,
                                                                  random_state = 10, 
                                                                  test_size = 0.5
                                                             

)
```

Answer (score 0):

Sklearn's OneHotEncoder does not support any input named 'n_values'...

Please refer to the documentation: https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.OneHotEncoder.html